# Outlook 2016 auto-removes zeros "0" in html tables

Tags: outlook, office365, exchange-server, html-email, outlook-2016

We are an ESP provider. We send messages for our clients in HTML format.

This week one of our clients complained that zero values ( 0 ) started being stripped from the email content by Outlook 2016.

This case is only relevant when 0 is located in

```
<td>0</td>
```

or in

```
<th>0</th>
```

In this case message source when opened in Outlook is:

```
<td></td>
```

or

```
<th></th>
```

Apparently, zeroes are being removed at the exchange server level since zeros are displayed neither on desktop nor on mobile devices for the same account.

Sending encoded zero as html entity fixes the issue:

```
<td>&#48;</td>
```

In this case message source when opened in Outlook is:

```
<td>0</td>
```

Could you please help me to identify what causes zero removals in html tables? Can we control it or this is a recent Microsoft bug?

Client confirmed that this issue started happening on Monday 03-19-2018 and emails rendered fine in previous weeks.

System administrators confirmed that they did not run any updates during the weekend.

Please let me know if you encountered similar issue and if you found a solution to it.

Comment: Is it happening only they exchange or outside of exchange server?

Answer (score 0):

Apparently it has nothing to do with exchange server. We researched email message headers and found that the client use Proofpoint software which filters created that issue.

Answer (score -1):

We had this same issue, we decided to separate the td tag in different rows, as several client use different Proofpoint configuration.

```
<td>
   0
</td>
```